# Files shared from OSX over samba locked

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, macosx

I am setting up a ubuntu 16.04 server and trying to get file sharing working between the server and my macbook running 10.11.2. I am quite new to ubuntu and believe this is a permissions issue. After a clean ubuntu install created a folder and went into 'Local Network Share' and turned on sharing, allow others to create and delete folders, and guest access. On my macbook I connect to the server through finder as a guest using smb://*the server ip*. The folder appears and I can drop files into it. However when I go back to the server the files are locked. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have the file server set up as ftp which is default.  This allows you to add files, but not pull files from it during a sync.  You need sftp.
Directions below.
http://xmodulo.com/how-to-set-up-secure-sftp-server-in-linux.html